# Duvida prolog, por que não é permitido?

Tags: prolog

Bom dia.
Estava respondendo um exercicio de prolog que foi-me passado pelo professor e realmente não conseguir chegar numa resposta pra tal, o mesmo pergunta por que a seguinte regra: **k(X),p(X),y(X) :- q(X), y(X).** Não é permitida em um programa na linguagem prolog. Alguem poderia me dar uma luz sobre? Já dei uma boa pesquisada e não consegui visualizar nada.

Answer (score 0):

As regras em Prolog possuem apenas um consequente (a "head" da cláusula).

No seu exemplo, lê-se "se q(X) e y(X) são válidos, k(X), p(X) e y(X) são válidos". Ignorando a lógica circular em `y(X)`, você poderia escrever em Prolog como cláusulas separadas:

```erlang
k(X) :- q(X), y(X).
p(X) :- q(X), y(X).
y(X) :- q(X), y(X).
```

ou, de forma mais compacta,

```erlang
k(X) :- q(X), y(X).
p(X) :- k(X).
y(X) :- k(X).
```